# How to always disable the “add saved file to map” checkbox in Save as ...?

Tags: qgis

I often use the "Save as.." dialog and just want the exported geojson file there. But he always enables the checkbox "add saved file to map". I really dislike it that way and it does not make any sense to perma-enable it.

Is there a way to permanently disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know,  there is currently no such option. It might make sense to change the behavior to remember the last used settings. This should be discussed in the form of a feature request in the [QGIS bug tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues) or on the [qgis-ux mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-ux).

---

Reported here http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12089

Infos on how to report issues/feature requests http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#bugs-features-and-issues

Comment: You Cannot Post Here This is a read-only archive. Anywhere this message there. I could justpost it here: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Quantum-GIS-User-f4125267.html

Comment: But I don't think that is the correct thing for it. Do you know why they do not open issues in Github? https://github.com/qgis/QGIS I mean everyone has Github, why not using this instead. I'm sure that there would be more issues this way.

Comment: @kwoxer Afaik, Github seems to lack some features which the developers want. Issue management for a project this size is not trivial. You can join the qgis-ux mailing list here http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-ux

Comment: I registered, but what now? I'm now here http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-ux/ but where can I post something. Wow there are so many better things instead of this like Redmine e.g. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems). Well could you maybe post it there? Thank you.

Comment: @kwoxer just send a mail to qgis-ux@lists.osgeo.org. 
The QGIS issue tracker is Redmine http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues. If you don't post it yourself, you won't get notifications.

Comment: Well I got enough e-mails I think :D do I need to create a new account on Redmine? I cannot find a registration there. MY Login data from the other page does not work.